# Drupal 7 not showing submenus

Tags: drupal, submenu

I'm using drupal 7 in my website, today i did an update of all the modules and after that the submenus dont showing, I have checked "Show as expanded" so, where is the problem?

When i login as admin, the submenus work, but when i refresh the page after, the submenus dont work

This is my webpage http://www.empleobelux.com/empleo/

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The menu doesn't have the classes that the superfish module's javascript is looking for.

Comment: Thank you for responding! so what can i do for solve this? sorry i'm new in drupal...

Comment: Are you using the superfish block to include the menu in your page? By default it would give you markup sumthing like the following: 

<ul id="superfish-1" class="menu sf-menu sf-main-menu sf-horizontal sf-style-default sf-total-items-5 sf-parent-items-1 sf-single-items-4">

Comment: I have seen that the file superfish.js is loaded in the source, but in the target <ul> apears like this:  <ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/empleo/programa_jovenes">PROGRAMA JOVENES</a></li>

Comment: Before the update, the class of the <ul> target was called 'menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow'. Now, the class of the <ul> target is 'menu'. and when i inspect the element with chrome a message appears: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined'

Comment: Sorry been away for a while. Did you fix this? If not this link might help https://drupal.org/node/2196635

Comment: thank you very much pete80!! the problem has been solved with the implementation of one of the blocks superfish in the webpage!! but i'll see the solution of your link mentioned for solve the sliders problem thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i fix this problem installing the superfish module and their library. I has had to place one superfish menu block at the page.

Now i'm getting another problem with the slider, it seems like the problem is because the jquery version has been updated and the function .browser does not work now. I have loaded the files jquery migrate and the problem persists.

```
http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/
```